# rvm: gems remaining after emptying gemset

Tags: ruby, rvm, gemset

I find that even after emptying a gemset, I still have gems.
Whats going on here?

```
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ rvm-prompt
ruby-2.3.0-preview1@infrastructure
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ rvm gemset empty infrastucture
Are you SURE you wish to remove the installed gems for /Users/redacted/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0-preview1@infrastructure?
(anything other than 'yes' will cancel) > yes
installing gem /Users/redacted/.rvm/gem-cache/gem-empty-1.1.2.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc.
Successfully uninstalled gem-empty-1.1.2
Removed successfully.
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ 
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ 
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ 
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.7)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
did_you_mean (1.0.0.beta3)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.2)
minitest (5.8.2)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.0.14)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (3.1.5)
~/gray/infrastructure (master)[]$
```

I'm trying to start my application with a clean slate.

Comment: These are the basic gems for Rails. Am I right ?

Comment: i haven't install rails on this gemset, so i doubt it

Answer (score 1):

Those are gems in the global gemset. See https://rvm.io/gemsets/global for info.

If you want to fiddle with them `rvm gemset use global` and then adjust as necessary.

Comment: I even tried removing gems from global gemset but some of them are not installed in global either